# How to turn a non-bindable key into a bindable one?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xkb, xmodmap

I'm talking about the <kbd>Menu</kbd> (keycode = 135) (aka Right Click), I don't use it

So I disabled its *contextmenu* action with Xmodmap tool, now it doesn't open the menu and still working for keyboard shortcuts*

Also disabled repeating itself with `xset -r 135` (Because keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  don't repeat themselves while they are pressed)

* But the problem is that I can't combine it with other keys, like how <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> does.

For example I can create a shortcut like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, but I can't do something like that with <kbd>Menu</kbd>+somekey, it doesn't bind with other keys. I'm able to create "chords" of keys but it's not what I'm searching for.

Looks like I can't do it with Xmodmap :/

If you run `xev -event keyboard` you can see that what changes with keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> is the **`state`** value, it goes from **`state 0x0`** when pressed, to **`state 0x4`** (In the case of <kbd>Ctrl L</kbd>) when released. That doesn't happen with <kbd>Menu</kbd> key and other non-bindable keys, all of them stays in **`state 0x0`**, maybe this is the problem?

How I can solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You misunderstand the Modifiers keys.

You can see what are your modifiers with `xmodmap`.

<kbd>Menu</kbd> is not a modifier by default, despite the fact it can trigger some contextual menus like <kbd>F10</kbd> (depending on the software you use).

When you see `state 0x0` in the output of `xev`, it is effictively related to the modifier, press multiple modifiers at the same time and you will see it sum up.

Effictively `xmodmap` will not allow you to create what you want.
Now, you can effictively try to add <kbd>Menu</kbd> to your modifier map with a valid modifier name, and modify your `xkb` map to ensure it will still send a keysym ... but it is not a elegant thing to do.

Let me suggest instead to use a software named `xcape` (there are others compatible with Wayland) to emulate a modifier <kbd>Hyper_R</kbd> (for example, and assumming you add it to your mod map) on this key when pressed in combinaison with others keys, and <kbd>Menu</kbd> when pressed alone.

[The documentation of `xcape` is really staightforward to accomplish such modification.](https://github.com/alols/xcape)